Nested For loop to populate API parameters
I need to write a nested for loop for a specific API. I started by creating a calendar dataframe to populate the API parameters and a date column in output dataframe.
The code for the calendar seems to work. The Ms columns are milliseconds that are required for the API. I have made them into a function in the for loop below.
calendar =  pd.date_range(start=(datetime.today() - timedelta(days=6)).date(), end=datetime.today().date(), freq='d')
calendar = pd.DataFrame(calendar)
calendar.rename(columns={0:'Date'}, inplace=True)
calendar['startMs'] = calendar.apply(lambda x: int(round(datetime.combine(x['Date'], datetime.min.time()).astimezone(timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000)), 1)
calendar['endMs'] = calendar.apply(lambda x: int(round(datetime.combine(x['Date'], datetime.max.time()).astimezone(timezone.utc).timestamp() * 1000)), 1)




Date
startMs
endMs




2024-05-29
1716955200000
1717041600000


2024-05-30
1717041600000
1717128000000


2024-05-31
1717128000000
1717214400000


2024-06-01
1717214400000
1717300800000


2024-06-02
1717300800000
1717387200000


2024-06-03
1717387200000
1717473600000


2024-06-04
1717473600000
1717560000000



Here is the loop I have tried variations of but none work. time.sleep(1) is to prevent the API from exceeding call limits (we have a rate of 5 calls per second). The goal is pull 7 days of data for each driver and then ETL it to the server. The driver loop works if I only pull it for a single day, it's when I try multiple days it fails. I made the driver table only 20 records for testing purposes and the output is always 20 records. I'm expecting 140 records (20 drivers x 7 days). Today is 6/4, the output I received shows the date column as having 6/3 only if that helps
for i in range(0,6):
    date = calendar['Date'][i].date()
    startMs = calendar['startMs'][i]
    endMs = calendar['endMs'][i]
    df = pd.DataFrame()
    for driverId in drivers['id']:
        response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers).json()
        url = f'https://api.samsara.com/v1/fleet/drivers/{driverId}/safety/score?startMs={startMs}&endMs={endMs}'
        df = df._append(response, ignore_index=True)
        time.sleep(1)
    df['Date'] = date

Here is info on the driver dataframe:
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 20 entries, 0 to 19
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------    --------------  ----- 
 0   id        20 non-null     object
 1   name      20 non-null     object
 2   username  20 non-null     object
 3   timezone  20 non-null     object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 772.0+ bytes

This loop works on its own:
# Today
value = 0
date = calendar['Date'][value].date()
startMs = calendar['startMs'][value]
endMs = calendar['endMs'][value]
df0 = pd.DataFrame()
for driverId in drivers['id']:
    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers).json()
    url = f'https://api.samsara.com/v1/fleet/drivers/{driverId}/safety/score?startMs={startMs}&endMs={endMs}'
    df0 = df0._append(response, ignore_index=True)
    time.sleep(1)
df0['Date'] = date

And so does this part of the code:
for i in range(0,6):
    date = calendar['Date'][i].date()
    startMs = calendar['startMs'][i]
    endMs = calendar['endMs'][i]

Or the suggested way:
for i in range(1):
    row = calendar.iloc[i]
    date = row['Date'].date()
    startMs = row['startMs']
    endMs = row['endMs']

I can't figure out how to get them to work together.
The response output when it does work looks like this, except it has real data:
for driverId in drivers['id']:
    response = requests.request('GET', url, headers=headers).json()
    url = f'https://api.samsara.com/v1/fleet/drivers/{driverId}/safety/score?startMs={startMs}&endMs={endMs}'
    pprint(response)

{'crashCount': 0,
 'driverId': 1234,
 'harshAccelCount': 0,
 'harshBrakingCount': 0,
 'harshEvents': [],
 'harshTurningCount': 0,
 'safetyScore': 100,
 'safetyScoreRank': '1',
 'timeOverSpeedLimitMs': 0,
 'totalDistanceDrivenMeters': 0,
 'totalHarshEventCount': 0,
 'totalTimeDrivenMs': 0}
{'crashCount': 0,
 'driverId': 1235,
 'harshAccelCount': 0,
 'harshBrakingCount': 0,
 'harshEvents': [],
 'harshTurningCount': 0,
 'safetyScore': 100,
 'safetyScoreRank': '1',
 'timeOverSpeedLimitMs': 0,
 'totalDistanceDrivenMeters': 0,
 'totalHarshEventCount': 0,
 'totalTimeDrivenMs': 0}


Make sense. Have you considered taking df = pd.DataFrame() outside of loop for i in range(6):?

Do not include solution to question please (post a separate answer instead).

Okay will do. Why did you take python out of the title, it’s a python script. Also I think the new title is technically wrong, the API parameters are already populated in a table, it’s getting the API response appended and storing the date within the response I needed help with.

df._append is used to append rows and in your case it seems that every key in the dictionary viewed as a new row.
More correct way is to do smth like this:
list_df = []

for i_day in range(0,6):

    row = calendar.iloc[i_day]
    date = row['Date'].date()
    startMs = row['startMs']
    endMs = row['endMs']

    for driverId in drivers['id']:
        # get json from the API
        resp = {'id': 22, 'name': 'John', 'username':'John', 'timezone':'utc'}

        # serialize data in the dataframe 
        # `index = [0]` indicates that we have only single row
        df1 = pd.DataFrame(resp, index=[0])

        # append new rows to final dataframe
        list_df.append(df1)

df = pd.concat(list_df)
print(df)


Never call DataFrame.append or pd.concat inside a for-loop. It leads to quadratic copying. Consider building a list of DFs to concat once outside loop.

See details from the authour:  The time.sleep(1) is just to prevent the API from exceeding call limits, we have a rate of 5 calls per second. T Thus you need to concatenate 1 new row in 1 second.

I tried this just now. I put the calendar suggestion in a loop and it works fine, but the driver loop is giving me a value error "Length of values (0) does not match length of index (1)" I tried removing the "index=[0]" and it returns an empty dataframe.

could you provide example of the response variable?
